# How to automate body import with Apache Tiles and Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, tiles, tiles2

I have the following tiles-def.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
<definition name="default" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/layout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="my webapp" />
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/header.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="menu" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/menu.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/footer.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="contact" extends="default">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/contact.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="hello" extends="default">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp" />
</definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

As you can see, in all my pages, just the body changes. Is there a way to automate this? (so it automatically includes the jsp that has the name of the requested page, or an error page if it doesnt exist?)

Thank you!

EDIT: More details of what I want to do:

How it is now:
For each new page of my webapp, I have to add a new  to my tiles-def.xml. And everytime, the only thing it does is setting the body with my content page.

What I would like to do:
Just have one default definition that automatically chose the page to display, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
<definition name="default" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/layout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="my webapp" />
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/header.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="menu" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/menu.jsp" />
    if(myPageName exists){
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" + myPageName + ".jsp" />
    else{
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/error404.jsp" />
    }
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/footer.jsp" />
</definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

Where myPageName would be the name of the page requested (If the URL was "http://www.mysite.com/contact.html", then myPageName would be "contact". If it was "http://www.mysite.com/info.html", then myPageName would be "info").

How can I do this?

Comment: @tsegay : I edited my initial post with more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Dynamic Tiles Example [on the springbyexample.org page](http://www.springbyexample.org/static/1.2/html/dynamic-tiles-spring-mvc-module.html). The DynamicTilesView does exactly what you want (see example config [here](https://github.com/spring-by-example/spring-by-example/blob/master/web/dynamic-tiles2-webapp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-context.xml)). The full Dynamic Tiles Example can be found [here on github](https://github.com/spring-by-example/spring-by-example/tree/master/modules/sbe-dynamic-tiles2)